# java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException after user removes pin patterns and adds pin and fingerprint

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-fingerprint-api

I am getting exception for below code

```
 try {
        mkeyStore?.load(null)
        val keyspec = mkeyStore?.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null) as SecretKey
 } catch {
      try {
            mkeyStore?.deleteEntry(KEY_ALIAS);
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Scenario is as below:

1. fingerprint is added and user registered using fingerprint in app.
2. Now go to setting remove pin(this also removes already enrolled fingerprints).
3. Now in settings add pin and fingerprint.
4. Open app again. As user is already registered using fingerprint , I am initializing cipher with above code. It throws the exception in try as well as catch block. User can't use fingerprint in app at all here on-wards. 
   (Android 8 - Samsung J600G)

Comment: Did you generate a new key after step 3? Any key for which `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` was used will become **permanently** invalidated at step 2.

Comment: my logic is continue with existing flow, if some exception occurs remove keyalias, any other saved data and then again generate key. This issue is happening only on Android 8. Tested the same piece of code on Android 9 and its working fine.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you're getting `UnrecoverableKeyException` instead of `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` in this case. What happens if you just ignore the fact that `deleteEntry` fails and try to generate a new key anyway? If generating a new key with the same alias fails you could try using random aliases instead of a hardcoded one (e.g. `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`).

Comment: As I mentioned earlier happening only on Samsung devices. Checked on Huawei with os version 8 , its working fine. I can try with random aliases but again saving those randomly generated alias is overhead.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to generate a new key with the same alias, even if `deleteEntry` fails. Only if that doesn't work would I try using different aliases for every key.

Comment: @Michael - thanks for the suggestion. As per your input I am randomly generating keyalias and its working fine.